# How to get current route name in react-navigation?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

I want the name of the current route or screen in react-navigation which I want to use inside if condition to make some changes.

Comment: React is such a mess with all the changes between versions.  The docs don't mention any of these & the code seems hard to figure out, I wonder how people even came up with these (old) solutions.

Comment: any way for 'wix/react-native-navigation', to get the current screen?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can catch it as the following code:

```
this.props.navigation.state.routeName
```

Comment: how do i check the current drawer routeName in a child stack

Answer (score 188):

For react-navigation v5:

```
import { useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';

const route = useRoute();
console.log(route.name);
```

Comment: You did not specify in which place should i use this useRoute() method. I am getting Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Comment: How to identify this scenario? Navigation directly to Contact screen. And Navigation to Contact screen through Home Screen.

Comment: It's good but won't work for nested routes.

Comment: It will also trigger rerenders on every route change. Just be aware

Answer (score 34):

If you are using nested navigators, you can use this code to get current active screen's state

```
import { NavigationState } from 'react-navigation';

const getActiveRouteState = function (route: NavigationState): NavigationState {
    if (!route.routes || route.routes.length === 0 || route.index >= route.routes.length) {
        return route;
    }

    const childActiveRoute = route.routes[route.index] as NavigationState;
    return getActiveRouteState(childActiveRoute);
}
```

Usage:

```
const activeRoute = getActiveRouteState(this.props.navigation.state);
```

I'm using this when I need to get current active screen's state from NavigationDrawer.

Comment: How are you injecting the route to the custom drawer?

Comment: Where does NavigationState come from?

Comment: @Hugo NavigationState is an import from `react-navigation`

Answer (score 20):

This works fine in react-navigation v5.x

```
this.props.route.name
```

Answer (score 20):

```
const routeNameRef = React.createRef();

<NavigationContainer
  ref={navigationRef}
  onReady={() => routeNameRef.current = navigationRef.current.getCurrentRoute().name}
  onStateChange={() => {
    const previousRouteName = routeNameRef.current
    const currentRouteName = navigationRef.current.getCurrentRoute().name

    if (previousRouteName !== currentRouteName) {
      // Do something here with it
    }

    // Save the current route name for later comparision
    routeNameRef.current = currentRouteName
  }}
  >
  {/* ... */}
</NavigationContainer>
  );

export function getCurrentRouteName(action) {
  return routeNameRef;
}
```

You can import the function getCurrentRouteName and use this to get the current route name and its working in any nested navigators in React Navigation 5.

Comment: Beware of this [gotcha](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/#handling-initialization)

Answer (score 17):

```
  import {getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute,useRoute} from '@react-navigation/native';

  //...
  const route = useRoute();
  const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route); // Get Nested Route Name
```

Comment: route.name also works

Comment: route.name doesent work for me, have to do the way oolala suggested

Answer (score 13):

While using `"react-navigation": "^3.0.8"` and DrawerNavigator it can be accessed from the this.props object using 
`this.props.activeItemKey`

Comment: with DrawerNavigator it does, are you using the same?

Comment: If you are using nested navigators, for example a StackNavigator inside a DrawerNavigator and need the `activeItemKey` say inside the Drawers `contentComponent`, how would you get it?

Comment: for a single route this works for me,  this.props.navigation.state.routeName

Answer (score 12):

In React Navigation v5, I was able to pull the current route name with the below approach:

```
import { useNavigationState } from '@react-navigation/native'    

const routes = useNavigationState(state => state.routes)
const currentRoute = routes[routes.length - 1].name
console.log('currentRoute: ', currentRoute)
```

Comment: Before using this, read the docs about it: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation-state/#how-is-usenavigationstate-different-from-navigationgetstate -> it's probably better to use navigation.getState()

Answer (score 10):

### Preparation

register [`NavigationService.js`](https://gist.github.com/1uokun/3827e11cf07f289c8d239f4bf9817144),see the doc detail in [Navigating without the navigation prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html)

```
<App
  ref={navigatorRef => {
        NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
  }}
/>
```

recursion function

```
function getCurrentRoute(nav){
    if(Array.isArray(nav.routes)&&nav.routes.length>0){
        return getCurrentRoute(nav.routes[nav.index])
    }else {
        return nav.routeName
    }
}
```

### get current routeName

```
getCurrentRoute(NavigationService.getNavigator().state.nav)
```

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to get this from the navigationRef attached to the navigation container. Where `navigationRef` is a ref.

`export const navigationRef = React.createRef()`

```
<NavigationContainer
   ref={navigationRef} 
   >
  <Navigator />
</NavigationContainer>
```

Then use:  `const currentRouteName = navigationRef.current.getCurrentRoute().name`

Alternatively in a functional component you can useRef `const navigationRef = React.useRef()`

Answer (score 8):

For react-navigation v5, you could use the useNavigationState hook -

```
import {useNavigationState} from '@react-navigation/native';

const state = useNavigationState(state => state);
const routeName = (state.routeNames[state.index]);
console.log(routeName);
```

Answer (score 6):

With version 5.x the best way currently is `getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute`

```js
import { getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function Stack(route) {
  // If the focused route is not found, we need to assume it's the initial screen
  // This can happen during if there hasn't been any navigation inside the screen
  // In our case, it's "Feed" as that's the first screen inside the navigator
  const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route) ?? 'Feed';
  return <> ..... </>
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const App = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const { dangerouslyGetState } = useNavigation();
  const { index, routes } = dangerouslyGetState()
  console.log(routes[index].name);

  return(
    <>
    </>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 4):

This is step by step procedure of what [Justin.Mathew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6386717/justin-mathew) has described in his answer.

Create a new file called `RootNavigation.js` and put the below content inside.

```
// RootNavigation.js

import * as React from 'react';

export const navigationRef = React.createRef(); // we will access all navigation props by importing this in any of the component
```

Now import the `navigationRef` from the `RootNavigation.js` file, and assign `NavigationContainer` ref to this. After this step `navigationRef` can function as navigation prop globally.

```
// App.js

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { navigationRef } from './RootNavigation';

export default function App() {
  
  handleNavigationRef = (ref) => {
    // DON'T DO navigationRef = ref, cause this will give you "navigationRef is 
    // read only" error.
    navigationRef.current = ref; 
  }
  return (
     <NavigationContainer ref={handleNavigationRef}>
        {/* ... */} 
     </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

**USAGE**

Now you can import `navigationRef` in any of the file, even nested ones. And can use this to get the currentRoute and screen details.

```
//SomeNestedComonent.js

import { navigationRef } from "path/to/RootNavigation.js";

const route = navigationRef.current?.getCurrentRoute(); //current route object
const currentScreen = route.name; // current screen name
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this in hooks as well.

```
console.log(navigation.dangerouslyGetState());
```

Answer (score 3):

In one line with useNavigationState Hook:

```
const screenName = useNavigationState((state) => state.routes[state.index].name)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **React Navigation v6** you can use this:

```
import { useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
...
const route = useRoute();

console.log('Current Route: ', route.name);
```

And if you want to get the name of the screen that you are, and you are **inside a nested navigator**, you can do this:

```
import { useNavigationState } from '@react-navigation/native';
...
const routes = useNavigationState(state => state.routes);

const currentRouteIndex =
  routes?.length && routes[routes.length - 1].state?.index;
const currentRoute =
  routes[routes.length - 1].state?.routeNames[currentRouteIndex];

console.log('Current Route: ', currentRoute);
```

Answer (score 3):

This simple code worked for me. Just add this function to your Util.ts/js file and from your component pass the navigation as the object.

```
export const getCurrentScreenName = (navigation: any) => {
      return navigation.getState().routes[navigation.getState().index].name;
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

***this.props.navigation.state.routeName*** works only in react-navigation 4 but react-navigation 5 doesn't support it.

The current route name can be achieved by using redux:

-Navigator component passes route object as a prop to the child component

-The Child component receives props and could find  the route name in ***route.name***

-To get updated route name on the screen change you can use *focus* event listener on navigation

<====== Parent Component where navigation is implemented ======>

```
import React from "react";
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-top- 
tabs";

import ChildScreen from "../screens/Home/childScreen";

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const ParentNavigations = () => {

return (

<Tab.Navigator
>
  <Tab.Screen name="ChildScreen" component={ChildScreen} />
</Tab.Navigator>
);
};

export default ParentNavigations;
```

<=====   Child component   =====>

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import ActionTypes from "../../store/actions/ActionsTypes";

const ChildScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
      dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.SETROUTE, payload: route.name }); // every time when screen gets focued it will update the route through redux
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation, route]);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Hello</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#0C0B0B",
  },
});

export default ChildScreen;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to see if the current screen is focused, you can use navigation.isFocused().
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#isfocused

Example:

```
_backAction() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    if (navigation.isFocused()) {
        this.setState({
            isLeavingApp: true,
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const Home = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  // you will see screen key, name and params
  console.log("ROUTE", route); 
  // rest of your code
};
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

For react native navigation 5.x use :

```
props.state.routeNames[props.state.index]
```

Answer (score 2):

We have a lot of answer here but it is hard to apply the fix because **navigation is NULL**.

**WHY?**

- Scenario 1: We are using hooks function like: useRoute, useNavigationState,... but **the navigation don't be mounted yet.** So it is null and get the Error.
- Scenario 2: We are using ***navigation*** object in the current screen like HomeScreen

  ```
  const Home = ({ navigation, route }) => {
     console.log("ROUTE", route); 
  // rest of your code
  };
  ```

but **navigation is NULL** in **Root** app with presence of **NavigationContainer**

**SOLUTION**
Make sure to checking navigation is not NULL by using onReady() method of React navigation.

```
const navigationRef = useRef();
const [routeName, setRouteName] = useState('');
return (
<NavigationContainer
  ref={navigationRef}
  onReady={() => {
    const currentRoute = navigationRef.current.getCurrentRoute();
    setRouteName(currentRoute.name);
    // Do whatever you want with navigation here!.
  }}>
  ...
</NavigationContainer>);
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

I have multiple `TabNavigator`s nested in a `BottomTabNavigator`. I get the current route of the `TabNavigator` with:

```
    const pathAndParams = props.navigation.router.getPathAndParamsForState(props.navigation.state) || {}
    const activePath = pathAndParams.path
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (I did it inside my navigation drawer)!

```js
const getCurrentRoute = nav => {
  if (Array.isArray(nav.routes) && nav.routes.length > 0) {
    return getCurrentRoute(nav.routes[nav.index]);
  } else {
    return nav.routeName;
  }
};

const currentNavigation = getCurrentRoute(this.props.navigation.state);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
const appNavigation = useNavigation();
const currentRoute = appNavigation.getCurrentRoute();
```

This worked for me. Navigation, and its state received as props were unreliable(at least for drawer navigator at root).
So I went with this one, which seems to be giving the global navigation state.

Had to use the navigation prop being received in drawer for drawer specific functions like `closeDrawer` or `openDrawer`.

```
export function AppDrawer(props) {

   // for closeDrawer, openDrawer etc.
   const { navigation: drawerNavigation } = props;

   // for referencing current route
   const appNavigation = useNavigation();
   const currentRoute = appNavigation.getCurrentRoute();

   // ... rest of the code
}
```

Reference for both the variable in console -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using reach navigation version 6 you can retrieve screen name by

```
props.route.name
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want get it in the DrawerContent

```
props.navigation.getState().routes[0].name
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass this prop to your Stack.Navigator:

```
screenListeners={{
    state: e=>{
         function findCurrentRoute(data){
             const state = data.state;
             const routes = state.routes;
             const currentRoute = routes[state.index];

              if(currentRoute.state) return findCurrentRoute(currentRoute)
              else return currentRoute;
         }
         console.log("CURRENT ROUTE NAME: ", findCurrentRoute(e.data).name);
     }
}}
```

Here, I have used recursion to find the deeply nested route.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me try this..

```
const getCurrentRouteName = () => {
    let _index = props.state.index;
    let _routeName = props.state.routeNames;
    return  _routeName[_index]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For 'wix/react-native-navigation' below is my working solution,

```
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';

// Create a variable and set the value from navigation events
let navComponent = null
Navigation.events().registerComponentDidAppearListener(event => navComponent = event)

// navComponent will have the following structure
{"componentId": "Component9", "componentName": "HomeScreen", "componentType": "Component", "passProps": {}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to get the **bottom nav** index as well, this was my method

```
import {useNavigationState} from '@react-navigation/native';
```

then

```
const routes = useNavigationState(state => state.routes);

let place = routes[routes.length - 1];

if (place.name === 'YOUR_BOTTOM_NAV_NAME') {
   if (place.state.index === 0) {
      //you are in the main screen(BOTTOM_NAV : index 0)
   } else {
      //else navigate to index 0 screen
      navigation.navigate('FirstScreen');
   }
} else if (place.name === 'Another_Screen') {
   navigation.navigate('navigate_to_the_place_you_want');
} else {
   //otherwise come to the first screen
   navigation.navigate('FirstScreen');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using version: "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8" and this.props.navigation, I did it like this:

```
    let navegState = this.props.navigation.getState();
    if (!!navegState)
        console.log('CURRENT SCREEN', navegState.routes[navegState.index].name);
```

Just use `navegState.routes[navegState.index]` if you want the whole object

Comment: You can destructure navegState like this

```const { routes, index } = this.props.navigation.getState();
const routeName = routes[index].name;```

Answer (score 0):

`'@react-navigation/stack'@6.0.11`

Worked for me but it's not the best approach.

```
const routes = navigation.getState().routes;
const currentRoute = routes[routes.length] // will be our current route .name for the name
```

If you want to look for a specific one

```js
navigation.getState().routes.find((route) => route.name === 'foo')
```

Comment: It should be 
`const currentRoute = routes[routes.length - 1];`

Answer (score 0):

For React Navigation v4

In my use case, I needed to access the current routeName in App.js outside of the  createAppContainer component so I did this...

onMount, set this.navigator to nav from  ref like so

```
 <App
   ref={(nav) => {
   this.navigator = nav;
   }}/>
```

Then when I need the current route, I access it via

```
 this.navigator.state.nav.routes.routeName
```

Answer (score 0):

If somebody looking to do this in expo-router,

```
const pathName = usePathname();
console.log(pathName);
```